# Theorem about Expected Value of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Well, we have to demonstrate this theorem but I don't have any hint.
I need to verify this:

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with values in the nonnegative integers and such that $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ exists.

a. Prove that

$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X\ge k)$

b. Verify that

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP(X>k)=\frac{1}{2}[E(X^2)-E(X)]$

But I just have the definitions of expected value in a discrete random variable. It is:

$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_kP(X=x_k)$ when this expresion $<\infty$.

I dont have any property, nothing. Just nothing. If someonce could help me, i would be grateful.

Sorry for the bad english. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
EX & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kP\left(X=k\right)\\
 & = & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(P\left(X\geq k\right)-P\left(X\geq k+1\right)\right)\\
 & = & P\left(X\geq1\right)-P\left(X\geq2\right)+\\
 &  & 2P\left(X\geq2\right)-2P\left(X\geq3\right)+\\
 &  & 3P\left(X\geq3\right)-3P\left(X\geq4\right)+\cdots\\
 & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq k\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $P(X \ge k) = \sum_{j=0}^k P(X=j)$.  Rearrange the double sum.